# Native crash? Android 6.0 crash makes no sense

Tags: android, crash, native

I recently updated my app to target SDK 27, before that it used to be 23.
And since I updated app I am getting the following error on GooglePlayConsole.
I did some research and from my understanding its native crash, but not much info on those and whats causing them or what they really are.
What are these native crashes and in my case what causes this crash? It makes no sense to  me at all

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000001fcd2c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb1EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+1827)
  #01  pc 0000000000200791  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb1EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+760)
  #02  pc 00000000000b035d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25796)
  #03  pc 00000000001e268d  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+312)
  #04  pc 00000000001fc221  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+332)
  #05  pc 00000000000c0ee7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26126)
  #06  pc 00000000001e25cd  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+120)
  #07  pc 00000000001fc221  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+332)
  #08  pc 00000000000c0b13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25146)
  #09  pc 00000000001e25cd  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+120)
  #10  pc 00000000001fc221  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+332)
  #11  pc 00000000000c0b13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25146)
  #12  pc 00000000001e25cd  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+120)
  #13  pc 00000000001fc221  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+332)
  #14  pc 00000000000c0b13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25146)
  #15  pc 00000000001e23a5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+84)
  #16  pc 00000000003e860b  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+546)
  #17  pc 00000000000eaef3  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
  #18  pc 00000000000e6781  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #19  pc 00000000003e9fb7  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+170)
  #20  pc 00000000000fb734  [stack:8757]
```

Comment: You chopped off a lot of the important part of the crash.  All we can tell from this is that the interpreter crashed.  The why stuff was above it.

Comment: I see, this is above my skill level, I didn't even know about interpreter. But that gives me a lead for further research. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your dependencies is hard to know, but keep in mind, since nougat (SDK 26), the native libraries are treated differently: 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

So, check your dependencies, find the ones using native code, and see if they were updated to support nougat's changes.

Comment: Ooh that explains it. I do have lots of libraries. Guess I'll have to test it now to see which library is causing it.